# When Browsing carousel is clicked it will open the browser. How can I return to my Action?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a Browsing carousel in my Action that opens a new page. From that page, I want to give the user an option to either continue on the website or to close the website and go back to the Action.

If they select the option to go back - how can I send them back to the Action?

Comment: Your question is a little vague and unclear about exactly what you're doing and what you are expecting to see. Can you update it, possibly with screen shots, to illustrate what you're seeing and doing and what you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Assume if Browsing carousel is pressed from user, it will open my web page. and then if user click open button ,it will do something but user click close button it will be back to conversation how can i do that on js. please help me.i'm sorry my skill english is very bad and this is a my first post. thank you.

Comment: @Prisoner Please let me know if you have some solution to get it through. thank you.

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question based on what you posted in your comment, but I'm not sure I've captured it correctly. Please check to make sure I have. Your English was fine - the issue was making sure we can understand what you expect the user to do and how you want the system to behave when they do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "go back" to the Action in the same way as if you clicked on a back button in the browser.

However, you *can* create a link on the page that you're showing the user that will re-start the Action or re-start it with a particular "deep linked" Intent. If you maintain the state of the user when they leave your Action, you can restore that state when they return, but that is up to you to manage.

To create a link to start the Action go to your [Action console](https://console.actions.google.com/), select the "Actions" navigation on the left, and then the right arrow for the Intent that you want to be able to link to.

[image]

Towards the bottom of the screen that comes up, you may need to click on the "Links" header to expand that section, and then turn the switch on for "Would you like to enable a URL for this Action?"

[image]

The section will expand to prompt you for a Link Title (which is required, but not really used for anything) and will show you an HTML code snippet with the link. You are allowed to change this link however you want, but you *must* use a link - you can't do something clever like try to redirect to that page.

[image]

Comment: This is what i mean. Thank you a lot for trying to help me.

Comment: i'm so sorry you again.it's hard for me to clarify the problem but you try to help me. Next time i'm going to improve when i will post the problem.